# No year in authordate1

Tags: bibtex, sharelatex

After I have compiled my code the following references is shown in the PDF-file:

> [Oestreich-Janzen, n.d.]

My bibtex database looks like this:

```
@INBOOK{Oestreich-Janzen,
author = {S. Oestreich-Janzen},
editor = {Lewis Mander and Hung-Wen Liu},
title = {{Comprehensive Natural Products II}},
chapter = {Ch. 3.25 Chemistry of Coffee},
pages = {1085-1096}
publisher = {Elseveir Ltd.},
year = {2010},
month = {March},
edition ={1st Edition},
note = {ISBN: 978-0-0804-5381-1}
}
```

My bibliography section looks like this:

```
\bibliography{referencer}{}
\bibliographystyle{authordate1}
```

I have included the *authordate1-4.sty* file in my project.

I use the `\cite{Oestreich-Janzen}` command

Can anybody help?

EDIT: Code sample

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english]{article} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{authordate1-4}
\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@INBOOK{Oestreich-Janzen,
    author = {S. Oestreich-Janzen},
    editor = {Lewis Mander and Hung-Wen Liu},
    title = {{Comprehensive Natural Products II}},
    chapter = {Ch. 3.25 Chemistry of Coffee},
    pages = {1085-1096}
    publisher = {Elseveir Ltd.},
    year = {2010},
    month = {March},
    edition ={1st Edition},
    note = {ISBN: 978-0-0804-5381-1}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
Text example \cite{Oestreich-Janzen}

\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{authordate1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurred because a comma was missing in .bib-file, so always remember to add comma between your statements in the bibtex database.

See the following code for the fix:

```
@INBOOK{Oestreich-Janzen,
        author = {S. Oestreich-Janzen},
        editor = {Lewis Mander and Hung-Wen Liu},
        title = {{Comprehensive Natural Products II}},
        chapter = {Ch. 3.25 Chemistry of Coffee},
        pages = {1085-1096}**,**
        publisher = {Elseveir Ltd.},
        year = {2010},
        month = {March},
        edition ={1st Edition},
        note = {ISBN: 978-0-0804-5381-1}
}
```

The missing comma is marked with two asterisks on both sides.